# What happens if we remove the pan from an induction cooker?

Tags: short-circuit, induction

When we remove the pan, the circuit will be shorted, right? Why it don't damage the cooker? Even if we use something like an MCB, it should trip something and someone needs to turn it on. Then how is it done?

Comment: If you have powered transformer, what happens when you removed the secondary side?

Comment: There's a Darwinian explanation for this. A cooker is designed to be used by non-engineers who will lift pans off it while operating. Any cooker that trips out or blows up when this happens will rapidly bankrupt their manufacturer, and these cookers will no longer be offered for sale. They **have** to be designed to tolerate this.

Comment: @Aaron That is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your induction cook top can sense when the pot is on top of it and switch itself ON or OFF as the case may be.
The current through the coil is being constantly measured and when it senses the pot being taken away it reduces the current.
So you can turn on an inductive cook without a pan on it and do no damage.